# How to configure wordpress to work with Vuejs with SSR and without hashbang

Tags: theme-development, themes, javascript

I am new on developing themes with vue.js and I would like to know how do I configure wordpress after removing hashbang from Vue.js router and on html5 history mode?

Another question is on this setup how do i perform SSR using Vue.js?

I am using Vue.js for the theme but if you know the technique for React or similar front-end framework, please share it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try Nuxt.js framework with Vue.js and WordPress as a server trough WP API. It works smoothly and have SSR solution in the box by default.

In other way you need to configure your server to work properly with history mode.

Take a look at configuration examples: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

And to official vue.js SSR docs: https://ssr.vuejs.org